# Disabling preview for emmet-mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, emmet

How can i disable emmet preview after expanding an abbreviation (pressing C-j) in emmet-mode for emacs?  I just want to expand an abbreviations with emmet preview showing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable preview only for current expansion call `emmet-expand-line` with universal argument (<kbd>C-u</kbd>) i.e. <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd>. To disable preview completely add the following to your init file

```
(setq emmet-preview-default nil)
```

From <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`emmet-preview-default`<kbd>RET</kbd>

> If non-nil then preview is the default action. This determines how
>   `emmet-expand-line' works by default.

The above will completely disable preview. In case you want preview for a particular expansion (after disabling it completely), you can call `emmet-expand-line` with universal argument (<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd>)